# Cannot run sqlite3 in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, sqlite, terminal

When I type in `sqlite3` into terminal (regardless of whether I include parameters or not), I am not able to run the command and instead get the following error.

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libreadline.6.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/sqlite3
  Reason: image not found
  Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Advice for resolving this issue will be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Version of OSX? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3166910

Comment: Odds are quite good you just installed Lion and need to rebuild all your ports [as described in Migration on the wiki](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration). Alternatively, you can use the version in `/usr/bin` instead.

Comment: Yes, this is after installing Lion

Answer (score 0):

After you upgrade your system to Lion, you'd better to run

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

this command will update port self and rebuild it's base system if needed.